# What does request.GET.get('page', '1') means here?

Tags: python, django

**views.py**

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator

def index(request):

    posts_list = Post.objects.all().order_by('-id')

    paginator = Paginator(posts_list, 5)

    try:
        page = int(request.GET.get('page', '1'))
    except:
        page = 1

    try:
        posts = paginator.page(page)
    except(EmptyPage, InvalidPage):
        posts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    return render_to_response('home/index.html',
        { 'posts' : posts },
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.GET

Comment: It means if the url of the GET request has `page` parameter, get it. If it does not, return 1 by default. So if the url has `?page=9` the `page` variable will be equal to 9. If it does not, the `page` variable will be equal to 1.

Answer (score 6):

Well this is a mix between Python's [`get`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method features and [`GET`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.GET) of Django,

Basically, since `GET` is a *A dictionary-like object containing all given HTTP GET parameters*, what you are trying to achieve here is find the value for the given key `'page'`. If it doesn't exist it will fallback to the default value `1` which is what `get` intends to do.

Comment: So, request.GET.get(....)  would return a string( for example "1") or an integer (like 1)?

Comment: @Mohd.Shoaib Well it will get exactly the type of whats in the dictionary for the given key, if not it will fallback to the value type you specified. So, in your code, it would fallback to the string `'1'`

Answer (score 3):

In simple way... you are using get() method that will check if the element that you want exists if not return None (null), so you are searching for GET (HTTP) Paramter if "page" exists, if not exists it return 1

```
mypage.com/?page=2

request.GET['page'] # That will force get page param, and you will if not found
request.GET.get('page', '1') # Tha will check if param exists, and return 1 if not found
```

**Using GET.get() is a bad pratice, since your erros will silent fail**, better your GET['page'] and handle the errors using `try/except`

```
try:
    page = request.GET['page']
    ...
except Exception as e:
    print(e) # handle your errors
    page = 1 # The Default value when erros comes
...
```

Comment: _Using `GET.get()` is a bad pratice_. That's not true. Especially considering how it used in OP question. It's a clean way of specifying a default value.

Comment: i used to get GET.get() while ago when alot people told me that is a bad pratice, because you fail it silent, in python style guild says that you should not pass errors silent

Comment: In that case, even passing default, you will not know the page where user came cuz your code always get 1 as default... so you will not know if was page 2, 3, 10, 20149

Comment: You're entirely right that it can lead to making errors go silent. But, what if this is what you want ? What if you want if you want to fallback to a default when an error occurs ? In both case I would go with `get`. Let's just say that your _bad pratice_ should become _It depends on the situation_ which are obviously not the same.

Comment: Better use try/except and when throw erro you capture it, handle it and set 1 as default

Comment: ye i understand you, im just saying this is a bad pratice, is better handle your errors than get used to do the easy way, that is ignore the errors and always use default values

Comment: i edited my post to set the default value to make the example more like his

Comment: To be fair with you i didnt check his entire code... look how he is already using try/except, but instead make it fails when getting the paramters, he will only fail when try to convert it to integer, its is kinda useless in that case... since he uses get() to fail silent, but uses try/except to handle the errors... you making one error silent when you trying to handle errors.